# "Another user Is editing this post" warning

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, editing, user-interface

Sometimes, I find that before I post my edit, someone already has edited the post.

Can't we make a system like this:
[image: like this]

Without the Feature

So, lets say User A started editing X post, and User B barges in while User A is editing. User A sends edit, few seconds later User B sends edit, which is less good. Good edit by user A lost

With the Feature

User A started editing X post, and User B barges in while User A is editing. Warning shown.. User B checks out new edit after A has finished posting. User A&B gusta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is already implemented as far as I know

- [The editing race - the slackers always win](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93169/the-editing-race-the-slackers-always-win)

Answer (score 0):

I think that we should enable peer editing with this particular situation so that someone else may choose which post is best. That way, there isn't any bias-based opinions. 
Also, Why not just make it into two separate answers? It may add a few extra lines but it may also be useful because the answers will be different.

Comment: On old posts that are maintained frequently, they would split into many separate answers. They would all be very similar to each other, they would all be very long, and most of them would differ only by minor grammar and spelling corrections or the addition of one item to a list. Also, splitting the edited post into two posts is inapplicable to posts that are questions (or tag wikis) rather than answers.