# When a post is edited, deny other users who want to edit the exact same post

Tags: feature-request, editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Another user Is editing this post” warning](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2445/another-user-is-editing-this-post-warning)

It sometimes happen when I am editing a post, that I can't save the edit because somebody else also started editing the post. Could it be useful when one user starts to edit the post the others can't, at least until he is finishing editing that post?

Comment: the accepted answer from that link, directed me to a meta.stackoverflow link but, the accepted answer there is the exact same msg box i get here. my question is could we DENY, other users from editing a post what is already being edited?

Comment: Though we don't have "deny" feature, but you will be warned when you start editing a post, which another one is editing at the same time

Comment: @AmithKK It seems to me that this is a request for a particular feature and [that question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2445/another-user-is-editing-this-post-warning) is a request for a somewhat *different* feature, this should not be closed as a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 5):

It wouldn't be useful to "lock" the post during editing.  It would just be a way for spam/rage posts to "lock" their posts to prevent editing out language or links.

Comment: +1, Good point.

Comment: very good point, didn't think about that!

Answer (score 0):

> Could it be useful when one user starts to edit the post the others can't,

Others actually can't edit the post

> when I am editing a post, that I can't save the edit because somebody else also started editing the post

It may also be possible that, the other users started editing before you.